# Member function query error

Tags: php, object, mysqli

I have a code wich is printing a multilevel menu. But it alsays says to me:
Call to a member function query() on a non-object in line ...
The query is correct, i have tested it in another document, and there it's working perfectly. I have researching a bit, but unfurtunately no suggestions has worked so far :/

The code is:

```
<?php $mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user" "pass", "db") or die ('Cannot open database'); ?>
<?php
function display_children($parent, $level) {
    global $mysqli;

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT a.id, a.label, a.link, Deriv1.Count FROM `medialib_cats` a LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT parent, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM `medialib_cats` GROUP BY parent) Deriv1 ON a.id = Deriv1.parent WHERE a.parent=" . $parent);

    echo "<ul class='nav'>";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row['Count'] > 0) {
            echo "<li><a href='index.php?page=folder.php&fid=" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['label'] . "</a>";
            display_children($row['id'], $level + 1);
            echo "</li>";
        } elseif ($row['Count']==0) {
            echo "<li><a href='index.php?page=folder.php&fid=" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['label'] . "</a></li>";
        } else;
    }

    echo "</ul>";
}
display_children(0, 1);
?>
```

Comment: Error is very clear. It says that you're trying to access a method while your entity is not an object. So figure out why it is so.

Comment: What does `var_dump($mysqli);` say?

Comment: Var dump print out a lot of informations, to long for the comment field - what you need to know? :) Some of it is:
[affected_rows] => 0
    [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Id: 731e5b87ba42146a687c29995d2dfd8b4e40b325 $
    [client_version] => 50008
 [connect_errno] => 0
    [connect_error] => 
    [errno] => 0
[error] => 
    [field_count] => 0
    [host_info] => hostname via TCP/IP
    [info] => 
    [insert_id] => 0
    [server_info] => 5.1.66-0+squeeze1
    [server_version] => 50166

Comment: have you put the var_dump code **in** the function (1 line before the $mysqli->query)?

Comment: Hmm then it's printing only Null. I guess that's what's wrong. Any idea how to solve this? :/

Comment: I would suggest you to pass the mysqli object as a parameter to the function like `display_children($mysqli, $parent, $level);`.